# How can I divide a total value fairly based on a differing range of values?

Tags: r, excel, google-sheets

I have a total value of x = $504, that I need to divide that based on a value metric in another column.

Manually, I was able to accomplish this, but I'm looking for a formula to help automate this process (in either Excel, Sheets, or R). I'm hoping to adjust X (or B8 in this specific example) to distribute and fill column $ accordingly, instead of having to edit the first cell under column $ to achieve the total of X.

```
VALUE  $
1      24
2      48
3      72
4      96
5      120
6      144
Sum =  504
```

Right now in sheets, I have B2 as the column I edit to help match final sum. Hopefully, I've stated clearly that I'd like to change the sum to "fill up" the column.

The table is realistic to what I need in that VALUE 6 is worth 6 times as much as VALUE 1 and VALUE 5 is worth 5 times as much as 1 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to multiply each cell by the `VALUE` divided by the sum of all the `VALUE`s, to get the right scaled number. Here's an example in R:

```r
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- tibble(value = 1:6)
x <- 504
tbl %>%
  mutate(dollar = value * x / sum(value))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   value dollar
#>   <int>  <dbl>
#> 1     1     24
#> 2     2     48
#> 3     3     72
#> 4     4     96
#> 5     5    120
#> 6     6    144
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

(Excel solution)

Assuming you want the values to be in column `C`

Put the following formula in `C2`:

```
=B2/B$8*C$8
```

and populate down

Then type in whatever value you want in `C8`

Answer (score 0):

Some simple arithmetic should provide a solution. Try this in B2 and fill down.

```
=504/SUM(A$2:$A7)*A2
```